# Optional commands for bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, arguments

I have a Bash script that sets various environment variables and runs a program. I want one of those variables to change if I run the command with an argument `debug`.

I know 100% how to do this in Lua code, but Bash is not Lua and I'm still in the early stages of learning it.

Essentially, when I run `./foo.sh` it does

```
export var1
export var2
export var3
program
```

I want it to *not* pass `var1` if I run `./foo.sh debug`

Comment: `if [[ $1 != debug ]]; then export var1; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
#!/bin/bash

export var1="value1"
export var2="value2"
export var3="value3"

program
```

into

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "debug" ]; then
    export var1="value1"
fi

export var2="value2"
export var3="value3"

program
```

The first command line argument to your script will be available in `$1`, and if that is not the string `debug`, `export` the `var1` environment variable.

The `#!`-line could optionally be changed into `#!/bin/sh` as the script (as written above) does not use any `bash`-specific features.

---

A variation of the above which does it differently with an array, without actually setting the variables in the script itself (only for the `program` when starting it):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "debug" ]; then
    vars=( var1="value1" )
fi

vars+=( var2="value2" var3="value3" )

env "${vars[@]}" program
```

or, for `/bin/sh`,

```
#!/bin/sh

mode=$1

set -- var2="value2" var3="value3"
if [ "$mode" != "debug" ]; then
    set -- var1="value1" "$@"
fi

env "$@" program
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. 
Quick question - Is there any difference in using #!/bin/bash vs #!/bin/sh ?
I've been using scripts for alot of automation lately in running wine programs with excessively long env variables needed, or to automate things like updating github files.

I know for the most part none of these are BASH specific functions, would it be better to switch to bin/sh instead?  Also, is ending the script with 'exit 0' necessary since it calls a program that operates out of the bash shell?

Comment: @JoshRaymond I tend to use `#!/bin/sh` on all scripts that does not use `bash`-specific extensions such as arrays or the `[[ ... ]]`-like tests etc. I do this mostly because I think it looks neater but also for portability (some of my scripts must run on systems where `bash` is not available). You should never have to end a script with `exit` as the last line of the script. An `exit 0` would also "mask" the real exit status of the script which would otherwise be that of the most recently executed command (`program` in your case here).